# Release / Retain by NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, retain

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSMutableDictionary * results;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * results;
```

and @synthesize results; in the .m

**THIS CODE WILL CRASH**

```
NSMutableDictionary * md = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

results = md;

[md release];
```

**THIS CODE IS OK**

```
NSMutableDictionary * md = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

results = md;
```

**Its clear to me that the pointer doesnt get retained, but i dont know why, did i made smth. wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

```
self.results = md
```

so md is retained.

You access a property with the dot syntax. By assigning something to a property with the dot syntax you call the setter which retains the value in your case. Without the dot you just assign the mutable dictionary to results, no setter is called.

You can read about [properties in Apple's Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17), look at **General Use** a bit further below the Dot Syntax paragraph.

Comment: so basicly i could do results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; and at viewDidUnload do the [results release]; and everything would be fine (iam not using = anywhere)? it would be even fine if i didnt even declare a property in that case... right?

Comment: Yes, using a property isn't necessary. There was a time before Objective-C 2.0 when there were no properties at all. Though I have to admit, I make constantly use of them, they help me doing memory management right.